# ICE from Frankfurt to Limburg

Tags: germany, frankfurt, deutsche-bahn

I need to reach Limburg a.d. Lahn, Limburg Bf, so when I search for trains online on DBahn, it shows many Limburg options:

[image]

I don't find many ICE trains to reach Limburg Lahn, hence is it okay to take any train that goes to any of the Limburg stations, or are they in different directions?

Comment: As a general rule, select one at random, have the system work out a route for you, and go to details, and then to map view, to see if the station you selected is in the part of the country you expect it to be. Often if you select one near the one you need you get a change of trains near the final stop, use that one to see if you get the wanted results.

Comment: If you are not sure which stop/station to pick just enter the street address of your destination. The planner will pick the closest stop and plan a route to it.

Comment: To get a quick overview, I suggest having a look at a map, e.g. http://www.öpnvkarte.de/#8.0777;50.3838;15  Don't try to get to the central station by train if you are coming from Köln or Frankfurt, it's a waste of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if a German city name has some qualifier like a river or geographic descriptor (e.g. Limburg a. d. Lahn, Kempten i. Allgäu or Weilheim i. Oberbayern), DB will name the station using the qualifier in brackets (so the above become Limburg(Lahn), Kempten(Allgäu) and Weilheim(Oberbay) – long qualifiers like the last may be shortened). Therefore, when looking for a train to Limburg a. d. Lahn, one would search for a trip to `Limburg(Lahn)` in DB’s list.

In case that is not enough to tell stations apart or in case the town name includes or used to include *bei* (near), this is explicitly given as a *b* within the brackets as for `Limbach(b Homburg,Saar)` in that drop-down list.

If, however, a city name with a qualifier has multiple stations associated with it, they may or may not all carry the qualifier. So *Limburg Süd* happens to be in the same Limburg as *Limburg(Lahn)* but the stations in Kempten are called *Kempten(Allgäu)Hbf* and *Kempten(Allgäu)Ost*.

In general, stations in these drop-downs go from important to less important. Limburg Süd is served by ICE trains which makes it important; Limburg(Lahn) is the most important station in the most important German settlement called *Limburg* and then all the way down to *Limbach(Vogtland)* these are smaller and less important railway stations.

After having a list of stations, DB often includes a list of bus stops (and tram stops or underground stations where applicable). They might not sell you a ticket all the way to whatever small bus stop there is but if they have timetable data (many buses in the countryside are still DB-operated but even within cities they have a surprisingly good access) they can give you a connection. I’m not sure whether `Limbach(Vogtland) Markt` is already a bus stop but I’m willing to bet `Limburg ZOB West` is. (ZOB is an abbreviation for ***z***entraler **O**mnibus**b**ahnhof or *central bus station* – train stations are practically never named that; if anything, a ZOB was built close to an existing train station.)

If you are looking for the city centre candidate, the top station on the list is usually the one you want but in Limburg’s case you’re looking to go to the central station which is `Limburg(Lahn)`, not `Limburg Süd`.

Answer (score 5):

In Limburg the ICE doesn't stop at the [Limburg (Lahn)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limburg_(Lahn)_station) (the main station in the city's center). Instead, the ICE only stops at [Limburg Süd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limburg_S%C3%BCd_station).